# setInterval() working intermittenly?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Why is this code working only part of the time?  Sometimes I'll refresh and the messages won't show whatsoever.  What could be causing this?  I tried putting it below, above, and using `$(document).ready(function())}` surrounding it.

```
var refresh_chat = setInterval(
function (){
    $('.chats').load('./php/get_chat.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 100 );
```

Comment: I don't know if it's causing your problem, but an AJAX call every 1/10 of a second is a bit much. You may want to increase that to 500 or 1000 and see if that helps.

Comment: Is there a reason to repeatedly perform a fadeIn() animation? In other words, are there conditions not mentioned where the chat is hidden between ajax posts? If not, you can simplify your life.

Comment: the fadeIn effect alone takes 600ms

Comment: Changed it from 100 to 1000 and then it wasn't showing it at all.

Comment: explain why you need the fadeIn effect, when are the chats hidden?

Comment: You really want `setTimeout` so its only called once, perhaps?

Comment: what stops you from debugging?

Comment: It's a chat so whenever something is submitted into the DB it needs to show that's why it's 100ms.

Comment: An average user won't notice a difference if you set a larger interval, also if you want the new content to fadeIn then instead of `.load()` you'd need a custom ajax call to append the content and apply the effect

Comment: I took out the fadeIn, I really don't need it.  I just want the data to show every second.  Why is it only working sometimes?

Comment: What cache headers are being sent with the response?

Comment: What do you mean by that?